# Unable to understand why is python2.7 behaving unexpectedly with input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python and I am trying to learn the language while also trying to see some differences between python2.7 & python 3.

I understand the fundamental difference between python2.7 and python3 with respect to input from resources like [this](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#parsing-user-inputs-via-input)

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
relation = {"saurav": { "age":21, "profession" : "student"}, "rini": {"age": 28, "profession" :"singer"}}
print(relation["rini"])
print("___________________")
print(relation["saurav"])
print("**************")
name = str(input("Enter name "))
print(name)
print(relation[name])
```

and when I run the above code in python3 I get the expected response. But when I run the same code in python 2.7, I get an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rish.py", line 6, in <module>
    name = str(input("Enter name "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rini' is not defined
```

This is how my output looks like:
[image]

Can someone please help me understand why am I getting this error in python2.7 and not in python 3?

Comment: See e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/; in general, changes between versions are covered in e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html. It's confusing that you say you understand the difference, but then ask why you're getting the error.

Comment: no, you don't understand the difference between python2 and python3. you need to use `raw_input` in python2. And why would you use python2 in the first place.

Comment: `input()` does very different things in Python 2 vs Python 3.  In Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: 2.7 tries to execute the input as code.

Comment: If you are learning the language, make your life easier and go with Python 3.